# Google Drive Android API List Files

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

Hi i am trying to get a list of files in my google drive.

I got this method from the google developers page, but it keeps giving me the same error, a similar method is used in some of the online examples but relies on the execute method call.

```
private static List<File> retrieveAllFiles(Drive service) throws IOException {
List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
Files.List request = service.files().list();

do {
  try {
    FileList files = request.execute() <--- Cannot resolve method execute;

    result.addAll(files.getItems());
    request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
  } catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
    request.setPageToken(null);
  }
} while (request.getPageToken() != null &&
         request.getPageToken().length() > 0);

return result;
```

}

Comment: What's the error? If there's anything in logcat, you should share that too.

Comment: There is no log cat, since the project will not compile at all. The only error it shows is the one above

Comment: If you are trying to list files on an Android device I'd suggest having a look at the Google Drive Android API in Google Play Services 

https://developers.google.com/drive/android/queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my error by importing all the libraries provided in the google SDK folder.

This file can be found here: 
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/drive/v2